# Breaking ocean waves simulation

Tags: unity, water, fluid-dynamics

I am working on a project where I have to approximately **simulate the ocean waves**. Currently, I am using a **mesh modification approach**. I am able to simulate low amplitude waves using the following equation:

```
yVal = Mathf.Sin(180 * Mathf.Deg2Rad / freqUpdated + Time.time * speedOFWave) * halfWaveHeight;
```

Now, I want to extend this equation to simulate [breaking waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wave#/media/File:Large_breaking_wave.jpg) for a high value of **"wave height"**.

**Approach tried:**

I tried creating code similar to this [plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sFCPfc7mDU) but the smooth transition between low amplitude waves to these breaking waves is not possible with that approach.

**I have the following questions:**

1. What kind of modification can be done to the above sin wave equation to simulate breaking waves?
2. Are there any other mathematical techniques that can simulate low amplitude and breaking waves?
3. Is it feasible to do this type of ocean simulation using water particles?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: what you mean about breaking wave? i dont think breaking a wave is something that be done with equation. you need some animation, spritsheet or shader for that

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am looking for an equation that forms a shape shown in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wave#/media/File:Large_breaking_wave.jpg). I am fine if the wave is not animating.